# How do I prevent <span> element from getting created if certain property in $root is null?

Tags: razor, knockout.js

I display some text in a `<span>` element which looks like this

```
<span data-bind="text: $root.participants()[_propkey].Currency"></span>
```

When **root.participants()[_propkey].Currency** is null, I get an empty space on page.

How do I prevent this span from getting created if **root.participants()[_propkey].Currency** is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [virtual elements](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) and the [if binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) to achieve what you're after

```js
var vm = {
  Currency : ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
span {background-color: cornflowerblue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
Currency span 
<!-- ko if: Currency -->
<span data-bind="text: Currency"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
is here
<br />

Test: <input data-bind="textInput: Currency">
```